# Updating fontawesome to 5.14.0 icons are displayed like squares

Tags: font-awesome-5

On a site i'am using fontawesome 5.13.1, so i want to udpate it to 5.14.0, so replaced the css files and after when looking on the home on my site the icons are displayed like squares.

I'am loading the library like that :

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/css/fontawesome/fas-5.14.0-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<span data-menu="menu4" style="font-size:46px; color: white; background-color: #8EC057;" class="bubble fas fa-bus-alt">
                                                                                        
                                          </span>
```

Do-you have an idea what's going on ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDN provided by Font Awesome and you won't have any issue

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css">

<span data-menu="menu4" style="font-size:46px; color: white; background-color: #8EC057;" class="bubble fas fa-bus-alt"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have uploaded on FTP the file fas-5.14.0-all.min.css which is just the all-min.css renammed and then it has worked. So i think the file has been corrupted during during upload